# Return true/false if users id is found in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new with mongodb. I am saving user recommendations in below schema. I am saving date on which user liked the business. I only want to return true/false if user id (uid) is present in users array.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    uid: { type: String},
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    _id: false
});

const businessRecommendationsSchema = new Schema({
    businessID: { type: String, unique: true},
    users: [userSchema]
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

I do not want to return whole object if present but only true of false. Please help.

Sample data:

```
{
    "businessID": "35M1L66a8YXzKmDYvbya3sHGJkH2",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2017-09-27T10:03:01.866Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2017-09-27T10:03:01.866Z"
    },
    "users": [
        {
            "uid": "PFwwUecwpFhhWCbJEaFjmfnGOix1",
            "createdAt": {
                "$date": "2017-09-27T10:03:01.867Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried below query but this only works if it is simple array not array of objects.

```
Business.aggregate()
.match({ businessID: req.params.businessID })
.lookup({ from : 'businessrecommendations', localField: 'businessID', foreignField: 'businessID',
as: 'recommendations' })
.project({_id: 0, businessID: 1, businessName: 1,
recommendedBy: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$recommendations", 0]}})
.project({_id: 0, businessID: 1, businessName: 1,
recommended: { $in : [req.query.uid, "$recommendedBy.users"]}});
```

Comment: Have you got any sample data and/or any query that you've tried already?

Comment: @dnickless Hi I added sample data and query I am trying.

Comment: I might be missing something here but it seems to me that your query works just fine? What exactly is it that doesn't return what you need?